# Do Android programming questions belong in Stack Overflow or Android Enthusiasts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation

Sometimes I do Android programming. I don't have any specific Android programming questions at the moment (since most have already been asked and answered), but it would be nice to know where to put them.

I know that general programming questions belong in Stack Overflow, if the question isn't specific to Android. (Example: "Why is this tree traversal code skipping some of the nodes?")

However, what about programming questions that *are* specific to Android? Do they belong on Android Enthusiasts – on grounds that they're Android questions? Or do they belong on Stack Overflow – on grounds that they're programming questions? (Example: "Why isn't this code consistently detecting `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` events?")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic,

> **What about other Android-related questions?**
>
> Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)

They are exclusively focused on *using* Android there, and such programming questions would be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Aha! I did the Tour, and checked for similar questions previously asked, but I didn't look on the Help Center (FAQ) page. I see that it's the first item there – *way* too obvious.

Comment: @Steve No worries, this is something people do get confused about on a regular basis.  We get the same thing on Web Applications.  Not sure what the solution is, though.